# Using CefSharp without a UI

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

I need to use the CefSharp web control as a javascript engine only (which will interact with my C# application), without connecting the control to a visible form. No matter what I've tried, unless I added the control to a form and showed it, I got an exception saying that the browser is not initialized.

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you looked at the `CefSharp.OffScreen` package?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - works perfectly well! Thanks